# My PHP code needs to display all rows; how can do this

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

Here is the website that shows my problem

http://teetimeqc.com/paypage.php

I want to show 1 entire row that EXACTLY matches the search query term on column 'cust_no'

Other columns are 'prog_id', 'balance', 'cust5_id'

So user searches for "140594", the entire **1**row displays along IF it's an exact match to the 'cust_no' of that row.

So they see results like this:

ID#  Prog ID# Cust No#  Balance #

**UPDATED CODE!**

Thanks so far jtherman for the help

```
<code>

 <?php

 $db_host="***";
$db_username="****";
$db_password="****";
$db_name="***";
$db_tb_name="cust";
$db_tb_atr_name="cust_no";


  $db_prog="prog_id";
$db_bal="balance";
mysql_connect("****","*******","*****");
mysql_select_db("db461563732");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);


$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 

 $db_tb_atr_name  = '".$query."'");
echo "<h2>Search Results</h2>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))



   echo ($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name]);

   echo ($data_fetch[$db_prog]);




mysql_close();

?>
```

Here's what the table looks like; Cust5_ID is not important, it's just an auto increment value I'm using as the primary key.....should I change the primary key to 'cust_no'?:

```
TABLE `cust`
(
    `cust5_id` Integer auto_increment primary key, 
    `prog_id` Integer not null,
    `cust_no` Integer null,
    `balance` Decimal(12, 2) null
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `cust`
(`cust5_id`,`prog_id`,`cust_no`,`balance`)
VALUES
(1,217770,145094,-178.01),
(2,219885,145113,-390.86),
(3,219888,145164,-206.55),
(4,226227,145279,0),
(5,227700,145340,0),
(6,219911,145344,0),
(7,227795,145410,-44.1);
```

Comment: what is the question again? if the user searches 145 you want to return nothing because there is more than 1 result?

Comment: yes, I want exact matches for the customer number or no results. I also want the row with adjacent columns displayed.

Comment: What if you change `like '%".$query."%'");` to ` `= '".$query."'");` that would make an exact match...

Comment: As a side note. Consider switch from mysql_ functions to PDO

Comment: @jthemanI just tried that.... now it displayszero results

Comment: Bla bla `mysql_` functions... bla bla deprecated.. bla bla injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Since the question was updated the error has changed. Now your problem is that the `while()` loop has an error in its syntax. Use curly brackets to start and end the while loop:

```
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result)) { // <- here
  echo $data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name];
  echo ", ";
  echo $data_fetch[$db_prog];
} // <- and here
```

However - if your database always only contain one single row for each cust_no then you might consider adding an unique index or making it the primary key, depending on how the number is supposed to be generated. Then you dont need a `while()` loop either as your query always will only return one row:

```
$data_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result); // <-load the single row into $data_fetch
echo $data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name];
echo ", ";
echo $data_fetch[$db_prog];
```

Also be 100% sure you have the correct credentials for your database.I would recommend you are using

```
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
```

as it seem now you are writing the credentials twice in your code (marked *****)?

Preferrably, as seen from your comments, using deprecated mysql_* functions at all is bad practise nowadays, you should really convert your code using PDO functions instead, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php  However that wasn't the scope of this question.

**Previous answers**

Change the line

```
 $db_tb_atr_name  like '%".$query."%'");
```

to

```
 $db_tb_atr_name  = '".$query."'");
```

that would make an exact match...

Then change the line

```
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,10);
```

to

```
echo $data_fetch['cust5_id'].",".$data_fetch['prog_id'].",".$data_fetch['cust_no'].",".$data_fetch['balance'];
```

to see a your result formatted how you want it.

Also change

```
echo "</li><hr/>";
```

to

```
echo "</li>";
```

The `<hr/>` part might make some browsers not render the list correct... Actually showing an ordered list doesn't make sense when only showing one result...

Comment: I did that....but now it displays no results no an error message for that matter....

Comment: And you search for a customer no that exist in db?

Comment: yes, I checked. I Changed the input type to "integer" and it returns a result but only displays the Customer primary key but not the rest of the row....strange.

Comment: What's the point of using substr for customer number in the line `echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,10);`? Why shorten a short value?

Comment: When I search for 145113 I get one line as result http://teetimeqc.com/paypage.php?query=145113&submit=Start+Search

Comment: Me too, However this query in Phpmyadmin works fine for example;

SELECT `balance`,`cust_no`,`prog_id` FROM `cust` WHERE `cust_no` = "145164"

It finds and display the entry I need....I totally can't get it to work outside of PHP.

Comment: I removed the list entirely. Check it out. It works...but I still can't get the row to display....

Comment: You had an error in your `while()` syntax. See my update. Also check the db credentials and my comment about PDO usage.

Comment: Tried both, converted the cust_no to primary. I get nothing now.

PHP is a complete PITA. I fixed the DB credentials....mind you they always worked before.

Comment: I copied your code and added the data to my local mysql and it works fine with both approaches. There must be something you foresee - the code runs fine.

Comment: I think my database is screwed up...I actually hired a guy and he complained about the same issues....I converted to amazon but now I can't even connect to their services!

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out....Turns out the display needed a div to show the requested contents and possibly deprecated code.

Comment: @WillWilkinsIII Sorry but why did you remove my answer as the suggested answer??? Even if no of the answers posted here is addressing your problem 100% I must say that my efforts were more elaborate!?

Comment: must have been an accident! OMG so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 

$db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%'");
```

I suppose it is

`"SELECT * FROM FROM ".$db_tb_name." WHERE ".$db_tb_atr_name."like '%".$query."%'"`

You are comparing an Integer as an String and also, if it is exact value, why do you use %?

`"SELECT * FROM FROM ".$db_tb_name." WHERE ".$db_tb_atr_name." = ".$query`